# Average speed for the whole journey

Tags: linear-algebra

"Xiu travels from town A to town B at $u$ km/h and then returns at $v$ km/h. Town A is $d$ km from town B. Calculate the average speed at which Xiu travels for the complete journey, in terms of $u$ and $v$"

Now the answers say 
$$ average speed = \frac{uv}{u+v} $$

What I tried was 
$ t_{1} = \frac{d}{u}$ and 
$ t_{2} = \frac{d}{v}$

so $ t_{1} + t_{2} = \frac{d}{u} + \frac{d}{v} = \frac{dv+du}{uv}$

and then total distance is $2d$ so

$$\frac{2d}{\frac{dv+du}{uv}} $$

= $$ \frac{2uv}{u+v} $$

Where did I go wrong? In my reasoning or algebra?

Comment: I don't believe you went wrong anywhere

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong? The average does not depend on $d$, as you have shown.

Comment: I think I'm wrong because the answers page says average speed  = $\frac{uv}{u+v}$

Comment: The answer in your book is incorrect

Comment: One more typo in a text book !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, the average speed is given as $$\frac{\text{total distance travelled}}{\text{total time required  }}$$
$$=\frac{2d}{\frac{d}{u}+\frac{d}{v}}$$

$$=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}}$$
$$=\frac{2uv}{u+v}$$

You are right. There is some error in the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP wrote and the comments earlier have already validated that.

Comment: OK, so O.P. is absolutely right.